# MPI_Send/Recv C++ std::string Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I've read a bunch of pages on here and posted a previous similar question to no avail and I just can not seem to find a workable solution.

This is a uni assignment with provided code to start off which is horrible but we have to use it :/ I'm not asking for a solution to the whole thing, just MPI_Send and Recv as I'm stumped.

Master:

```
string parent; //Is initialised to a random sequence of characters before I try the send
int parentSize = parent.size()+1;

for (int i = 1; i < processes; i++)//Send current parent to slaves
{
    MPI_Send(&parentSize, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, i, MSIZE, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //This works fine
    MPI_Send(&parent, parent.size(), MPI_BYTE, i, MSEND, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Slaves:

```
int parentSize;

MPI_Recv(&parentSize, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, 0, MSIZE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //Works fine
MPI_Recv(&parent, parentSize, MPI_BYTE, 0, MSEND, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //Gives a segfault when I try to cout parent
```

Am I allocating an incorrect amount of memory? I believe size() will return the number of chars in the string (28) and + 1 for null terminator?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MPI, but I can tell you that `std::string::size()` does not return length of string + null terminator, it returns just the number of characters. `std::string` is supposed to abstract away the notion of null terminators (if it even uses one at all, I am not sure) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: The number of characters is the length and I add 1 manually to account for the NULL terminator. The doco I read said they were synonymous.

Comment: oh derp, that totally went over my head xD. I think the answer given has a better idea, since *technically* `std::string` and c-strings (`char *` w/ NULL terminator) are not synonymous. IIRC, `std::string` may be represented as a c-string, but may over-allocate as well as stores other meta-data.

Comment: `std::string` allocates memory for strings dynamically and `&parent` gives the address of the object and not of the string buffer. You should get a pointer to the actual string buffer with `std::string::c_str()`. Also the count when sending `parentSize` should be `1` - you have already specified that the type is `MPI_INT` and therefore MPI will take `sizeof(int)` bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to MPI_Send(parent.c_str(), parent.size()....); and receive a char buf[parentSize] from the other side.

Comment: I have tried this but it seemed to just get more complicated as I would have to keep converting a bunch of times and it was just messy so a solution without having to would be preferable because I have to use the given code with uses std:string :/

Comment: If you don't mind using boost then you could do it right away. Example at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.point_to_point. (I assume the lib handles that conversion for you behind the scene)